# Why does a <Link> tag content falls a step behind compared to an <a> tag in React?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, calendar, tags, use-state

Here's my code below, it shows different spreadsheets at different links, defined by the "duration" variable. I click on a calendar date, and it takes me there, the only problem is it always falls behind one step, so basically I have to double-click on a date to get there. If I use "a" tag instead of "Link", it works fine, but I don't want to, because it refreshes the whole page, so "Link" is more convenient in this case.

P.S I know it has something to do with the async UseState I'm using, but if I simply display {duration} in the react component, it changes on the click immediately and it doesn't fall behind, so definitely has something to do with the "Link".

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Calendar from "react-calendar";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export function getSunday(d) {
  d = new Date(d);
  return new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay()));
}

const ReactCalendar = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const minDate = new Date(2022, 3, 3);
  const maxDate = new Date(2032, 3, 4);

  const onChange = (date) => {
    setDate(date);
  };

  let duration = Math.floor((date - minDate) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7);

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={`/employerX/Home/${duration}`}>
        <div className="menu">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Calendar</a>
              <div className="menu-1">
                <Calendar
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                  value={date}
                  minDate={minDate}
                  maxDate={maxDate}
                />
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReactCalendar;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is to route to a url `/employerX/Home/${duration}` whenever a new date is selected.

If so, wrapping the Calendar component in a Link component is not really the right way to do so. Links should generally contain simple elements.

You can make use of the [useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook from react-router-dom instead.

Your component would look something like this

```js
    const ReactCalendar = () => {
      
      const history = useHistory();

      const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
      const minDate = new Date(2022, 3, 3);
      const maxDate = new Date(2032, 3, 4);
    
      const onChange = (date) => {
        setDate(date);

        let duration = Math.floor((date - minDate) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7);
        history.push(`/employerX/Home/${duration}`);
      };
    
      return (
            <div className="menu">
              <ul>
                ...
              </ul>
            </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default ReactCalendar;
```